# Aligning two lines at many ='s

Tags: align

I want to align two lines at many ='s.
For example, TeX considers the following code to be having there are two expressions in each line.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
f(x) &= (x+1)^2+x &= x^2+3x+1 \\
g(x) &= (x+1)^3 &= x^3+3x^2+3x+1
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I want to display it like this.

```
f(x) = (x+1)^2+x = x^2+3x+1
g(x) = (x+1)^3   = x^3+3x^2+3x+1
```

Is such a display possible?

Comment: Is that the effect you were aiming for? I used code sample markdown as it gives you a monospace font and prints all input verbatim

Comment: Not that, for `n` alignment groups,  you need to write `2n – 1` ampersands, not n.

Comment: @Au101: Thank you.That's exactly the effect I was aiming for.And I edited one of my sentences in terms of English grammmer.

Answer (score 8):

Something like this?

[image: alignment with specified spacing]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
f(x) &= (x+1)^2+x &&= x^2+3x+1 \\
g(x) &= (x+1)^3   &&= x^3+3x^2+3x+1
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Off-topic, but if you have `a4paper` as a class option, then you probably want

```
\usepackage{geometry}
```

to ensure that the page is laid out in a way which matches the dimensions of the paper. Otherwise, subtle weirdnesses result.

Comment: `geometry` (without options other than `a4paper`) just makes a decision about the page parameters, which is as valid as the default one. I don't understand what “subtle weirdnesses” you're talking about. I could agree if it was `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}`. Anyway, TeX Live is set up to use A4 paper by default.

Comment: I agree that `geometry` with just `a4paper` does fine. But `a4paper` without `geometry` does not, for me at least. (This would be equivalent to using `a4paper` with `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}`, I assume.)

Comment: @egreg ^^ Also, TeX Live is not necessarily set up to use A4 by default. Yours maybe. Mine is. The OP's may not be. This is a choice you make on installation. But even when TL uses A4 by default, `article` does not. So the layout of the page does not match the paper. At least, that's how it works for me. Perhaps you have things configured differently and I've just missed a needed option somewhere.

Comment: @egreg [Or something like that. I get wrong results with `a4paper` without `geometry`, anyway.]

Comment: @egreg @cfr: Thank you.I changed into `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}`.Without `\usepackage{geometry}` or with `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}`,nothing weird happened in my environment(debian jessie).But when I changed the first line into `f(x) &= (x+1)^2+x &&= x^2+3x+1 &&= x^2+3x+1 &&= x^2+3x+1 \\` without geometry and so, the line number protruded from the line into the subsequent line.I'm trying to understand the function of alignat and ampersand $ now.

Comment: I also tried with `\seqsplit{\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323679/latex-in-a-two-column-elsevier-it-is-not-possible-to-fit-figures-in-whole-page}}`,the line is cut off in the midstream even with `geometry`. Should I post anther question?

Comment: @drop-in Probably best to post a new question with an example of the new problem as I'm not entirely certain what you tried. What is `\seqsplit{\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323679/latex-in-a-two-col‌​umn-elsevier-it-is-not-possible-to-fit-figures-in-whole-page}}` supposed to do? Why `\seqsplit` for a URL?

Comment: @drop-in For `f(x) &= (x+1)^2+x &&= x^2+3x+1 &&= x^2+3x+1 &&= x^2+3x+1`, it makes no sense to use `alignat` as this aligns things when you have multiple equations on subsequent lines. If you only have one line and one equation, there's nothing to align. Probably the line is just too long and you need to split the equation, which is a different issue from the one you asked about here. Or have I misunderstood what you're doing?

Comment: @cfr: Sorry.My explanation was bad.The code I tried without `geometry` or so is`\begin{alignat}{4} f(x) &= (x+1)^2+x &&= x^2+3x+1 &&= x^2+3x+1 &&= x^2+3x+1 \\ g(x) &= (x+1)^3   &&= x^3+3x^2+3x+1 &&= x^3+3x^2+3x+1 &&= x^3+3x^2+3x+1 \end{alignat}`.

Comment: @cfr: Sorry,too.I made mistakes in copying and pasting.After Adding the preamble `\usepackage{seqsplit}`,the right code for the purpose is `\url{\seqsplit{the URL}} \\ `. I want the hyperlink to be properly wrapped in the generated pdf(dvi). `\seqsplit` works well for ordinary texts.`\seqsplit{\url{the URL}} \\ ` is displayed as just an ordinary text in the generated pdf(dvi).

Comment: @drop-in It would be better to use the `url` package, with customisation if desired. URLs ought not be broken arbitrarily but at specific points.

Answer (score 6):

Or, if you prefer a single equation for both (curly bracket optional)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \left\{
        \begin{alignedat}{2}
    f(x) &= (x+1)^2+x &&= x^2+3x+1 \\
    g(x) &= (x+1)^3 &&= x^3+3x^2+3x+1
    \end{alignedat} \right.
        \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For fun, some trickery with `\hphantom`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
f(x) &= (x+1)^2+x = \hphantom{x^3 + 3}x^2+3x+1\\
g(x) &= (x+1)^3\hphantom{{}+x} = x^3+3x^2+3x+1
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you.Tha's also nice.BTW,whether choosing `\hphantom{x^3 + 3}` or `\hphantom{x^3 + 3{}}` doesn't make any difference.What is the function of `{}` here?

Comment: @drop-in The curly braces are important for the other case `\hphantom{{}+3}` because of the binary atom `+`. Binary operators are set with additional horizontal spacing (`\medmuskip`). If the binary symbol is not surrounded by two appropriate other math atoms, then TeX strips this property from the symbol and it is set as ordinary symbol (see the unary minus sign). The curly braces form an empty subformula, which act as invisible left part for the binary plus symbol.

Comment: Thanks again.I understand well now.A code `\begin{align}`　`f(x) &= (x+1)^2+ \\ `　`f(x) &= (x+1)^2+x`　`\end{align}` shows the difference.

Comment: I don't know why, but `@HeikoOberdiek:` or `@heiko:` disappeared from my previous comment.

Comment: @drop-in It is redundant and gets removed, because the author of the answer (me in this case) automatically gets notified.